# When I start my machine it show error

Tags: boot

When I see this error I do some research and run both these command but still issues is remain same [image]

Comment: Those failed to fetch error messages mean that you are not connected to the internet.

Comment: You have two problems - one is whatever theme you're using is busted, it's trying to read a file that doesn't exist.  And you can't reinstall the theme or such because you have no internet access - chances are you aren't connected to the Internet because you need Network Manager (loaded at login/startup) to initiate your Internet connection.  Are you using a wifi connection?  Have you done any recent system changes or updates before this began happening?

Comment: yes I have internet connection and i did some changes before this began happening actually i had installed so many themes  and i removed them